# Shy and nervous kittens are too scared to eat

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding, containment

I recently adopted two kittens (both are siblings) and since having them I've noticed they are extremely nervous and scared. They only come out when nobody is home, and I'm trying to get them used to me.

I've set up them up in one room with their cat bed (its a hooded one for some shelter) some litter box trays and water.

I've been trying to feed them about twice a day, and when I do, I try to get really low to the ground (sometimes I'll just lay down on it) and either have different food bowls around the room so they can explore the room with me in it. Or, I'll have the food in front of their bed and just lay away from them.

One of the kitties, will eat with me in the room. He will get out of his cat bed, and he'll even travel across the room to use the litter box or sniff things when I'm around. However the other kitty will not budge from the cat bed. I tried to place the food bowl as close as possible to the bed and she will still not poke her head out enough to eat.

At this point I'm just so worried and I want her to eat something. But I'm unsure of how to get her to eat. I had to grab them once out of their bed and I know its really bad to keep doing that and so I'm trying to avoid that at all costs. But, if I just place more food bowls near the bed, eventually the braver kitty will eat the food instead. If anyone has any suggestions, I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. :) I'm curious, are you leaving food out through the night, or during the day when you are gone?

Comment: I do leave some dry kibble out during the night time. But I don't think they are eating it. 

Usually I feed them when I'm home (usually i mix wet food with dry kibble in hopes that they get used to the kibble). In the afternoon and then a little towards evening.

Answer (score 6):

The new kittens are getting used to their new surroundings. Follow their animals instinct...hunt, kill, eat, groom, sleep. Get them playing and "hunting", try to wear them out, then give them some food. If they are hungry, they will eat. Try different foods too, maybe they aren't interested in the food you are offering. My two cats love bonito flakes on top of their wet food.

Kittens need to play a lot. They have lot of energy, so invest in some fun toys, or make toys (a ball of tin foil and shoelaces go a long way). Get them climbing, running, pouncing, etc...They will gain confidence and feel safer in the space, and, gradually, they will explore more of your house. When they are hungry they will eat.

Play, eat, sleep repeat!

Comment: Wet food is definitely the best for kittens, because it's easy to eat and smells "amazing" (to them, haha). Plus, wet food is more filling and nutritious for their early years :)